# raspberry stretch gazebo9

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

Installing ROS on Raspberry, following
https://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

Step 3.1 Create a catkin Workspace
I used Desktop rather than ROS-com

Step 3.2.1 Unavailable Dependencies
Completed. (is this still required by the way ? )

Step 3.2.2 Resolving Dependencies with rosdep
Fails:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo9 : Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.0.0-2~stretch) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: gazebo9-common (= 9.0.0-2~stretch) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gazebo9-plugin-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gazebo9] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [gazebo9]
```

I did install manually the dep (see http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23350/libgazebo9-dev-unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-1804 ):

```
sudo apt-get install libignition-math4-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdformat6
sudo apt-get install libgazebo9
```

These went ok. Then:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ sudo apt-get install -y gazebo9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gazebo9 : Depends: libgazebo9 (= 9.0.0-2~stretch) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: gazebo9-common (= 9.0.0-2~stretch) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gazebo9-plugin-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then: Kinetic comes with gazebo7 not 9. (see here : https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/issues/10340 ) So:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebot7
```

Went ok. But that still does not pass the rosdep

So I am kinda stuck there.  Any idea ?

see also :
https://answers.ros.org/question/260813/help-please-failure-install-ros-on-raspberry-pi/
-> yes, raspberry is too broken-winded to run gazebo, not my intend. Nevertheless :

1. I failed badly at using the bare-bone install previously, with problems during catkin_make  (geometry_msgsConfig.cmake geometry_msgs-config.cmake not beeing found). I am more confident with the 150% solution now, if available .
2. the ROS doc says that install desktop install is an option (even if the other one is the recommended one). So, shall work somehow...

P.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340809/raspberry-stretch-gazebo9/) by [Piter_Pam](https://answers.ros.org/users/50572/piter_pam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2019-12-30**:
I had this problem in Ubuntu . What I did was to purge all ros and then reinstall with minimal version and install gazebo separately. Somehow after removing gazebo it messes up dependency tree and everything seems broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok,

I was not able to solve my dependency problem here.
I did reinstalled with the recommended ROS-Comm option.

P.

---

Originally posted by [Piter_Pam](https://answers.ros.org/users/50572/piter_pam/) with karma: 16 on 2020-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-03-07**:
For future reader: A similar question has been answered at https://answers.ros.org/question/345752/ros-kinetic-installin-gazebo-9-rather-than-gazebo-7/